# Who's not welcome here?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Five people are discussing their hobbies:

> "I like baseball", says a man.
>   "I prefer hiking", answers a woman.
>   "I love persian culture", tells a second man.
>   "It's weird, but I like to slice things up", says another woman.
>   "As for me, I really enjoy eating in the evening", tells the last man.

After a brief pause, one of them finally says:

> "Well, I guess I'm not welcome here, so I'll see myself out."

**Who is it, and why?**

Comment: "I like to cut things" - "Ok" - "I like baseball" - "What? You monster"

Comment: This person was probably Keelhaul. And soon after that he posted this riddle just to complain about weirdos he has to deal with.

Comment: that clickbait title.. have a +1

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I'm going to guess it's the

> Persian culture guy,

based on the observation that

> the people could very well be misunderstood or **mispronounced super heroes**.

Particularly, they could be

> Batman (baseball bat), Wonder Woman (wander woman), Iron Man (Iran Man), Catwoman (cutwoman) and Superman (supperman).

So, the odd one out would then be

> Iron Man, because the others are DC characters, and he's the only Marvel hero.

Comment: I like this answer, +1!!

Comment: Finally, we have a winner!

Comment: Then couldn't it be rot13(Pngjbzna) since that is the only one often considered a rot13(ivyynva)?

Comment: Keeta has a good point. I think both are valid interpretations.

Comment: @Keeta and jafe, Yeah, probably, although I'd say she has more of an anti-heroine (opposed to drugs?) kind of vibe going on there. I'm sure Keelhaul would have accepted either answer though, because the actual point of the puzzle is in another place entirely.

Answer (score 12):

This is probably a stretch but it somehow fits.

> Woman who likes to slice things up?

Because

> She 'saw' herself out.

Comment: Nope, try again :p

Comment: +1 for the sweet pun

Comment: @El-Guest Had to do it :P

Answer (score 7):

*(Not meant to hurt any social, religious and/or political sentiment)*

Is it an

> Israeli Jew?

"I like baseball", says a man.

> On [this](https://www.topendsports.com/world/lists/popular-sport/sports/baseball.htm) website, Iraq is ranked 6th in regional popularity of baseball around the world.

"I prefer hiking", answers a woman.

> In order to hike, you need a navigable route i.e. mountain pass. The
>  Zagros mountain ranges of Iraq have these in plenty.

"I love persian culture", tells a second man.

> The large number of Shia Muslim population means a shared culture with Iran (i.e. Persia).

"It's weird, but I like to slice things up", says another woman.

> Due to the large Muslim population, this may refer to slicing of meat 
>  and beef as per [Halal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halal) conventions.

"As for me, I really enjoy eating in the evening", tells the last man.

> This probably refers to [iftar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iftar) 
>  during the [Ramadan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramadan) fast.

"Well, I guess I'm not welcome here, so I'll see myself out."

Why?

> From the above, it is clear that the above group is that of Shia Muslims 
>  living in Iraq. Now, where might these people be living in? A place in
>  Iraq where there is local diversity. What better palce than Baghdad
>  may fit this criteria. The Israeli Jew may feel that the group is unsafe
>  and leave it on account of March 1950 Denaturalisation Act and [1950–1951 Baghdad bombings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1950%E2%80%9351_Baghdad_bombings), wherein
>  hundred thousand of Iraqi Jews were targets of a series of bombings in Baghdad.

Comment: This is a really interesting answer, I had never considered this angle!

Comment: That's absolutely not the answer :p. This is a riddle, with a clear answer once you got it, not a geopolitical parabola ;)

Comment: @Keelhaul Do you mean parable?

Comment: This answer seems to have missed the detail that it was one of the original 5 speakers who left ("one of them").

Comment: @Acccumulation Maybe :)

Answer (score 5):

## Answer:

It is

> **The second man**, who tells of loving **Persian culture**.

Why?

> Because he is the only person out of the five people who does not relate to a **card suit**.

$$$$

## Explanation:

`"I like baseball," says a man.`

1. > The first man loves **baseball**. In baseball, the field is in the shape of a **diamond** $\to$ diamond cardsuit $\diamondsuit$. He is a man because the infix "mon" in the word, *diamond*, sounds like **man**.

`"I prefer hiking," answers a woman.`

2. > The first woman prefers **hiking**. In the very word, there is a mention of **king** $\to$ the king in a deck of cards. She is a woman for she is **queen** to the king (because she *loves* $\heartsuit$ hi**king**, a reference to the **hearts** card suit).

`"I love Persian culture," tells a second man.`

3. > The second man loves **Persian culture** $\to$ no cards related. (Odd one out.)

`"It's weird, but I like to slice things up," says another woman.`

4. > The other woman likes to **slice things up**. You can use a **spade** to dig and/or slice things with its sharp edge $\to$ a spade cardsuit $\spadesuit$. (There are also many slicing card magic tricks.) She is a woman because when upside-down, the spade looks like a **heart** $\require{HTML} \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(180deg)}{\spadesuit}$, another card suit $\heartsuit$. Or, she being a woman might (additionally) be referencing [Kate **Spade**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kate_Spade) who was a **fashion designer** (and recently passed away by suicide, how tragic).

`"As for me, I really enjoy eating in the evening," tells the last man.`

5. > The last man **enjoys eating in the evening**. This hobby has nearly all words starting with *e* (**e**njoys **e**ating in the **e**vening), which is the suffix of the word **tree** (and sounds like the word too, as well as the word, *really*, and *me* in "as for me") $\to$ the **clubs** cardsuit that looks like a tree $\clubsuit$. He is a man because the sport **golf** is mostly played by **men**, a reference to golf **clubs** (and he might be using a dining gift **card**!).

`After a brief pause, one of them finally says:` 
 `"Well, I guess I'm not welcome here, so I'll see myself out."`

> i.e. **the second man**.

Comment: That's... quite far-fetched, but I like the idea! This riddle have already been answered though, but have a +1

Comment: This is definitely no more far-fetched than the actual answer... Well done, @user477343!

Answer (score 4):

> Person who likes Baseball cannot play alone.The one who prefers hiking can go to hiking alone. The one who loves Persian culture can read about them alone.The one who loves to slice things up can slice some vegetables or fruits and cook something for the person who loves to eat. So there's no one to play with the baseball guy.

Comment: welcome to puzzling SE , please add spoiler tags before posting your answers, for more help visit the help center. Happy Puzzling.

Comment: That is not the answer, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

This may be far too simple, but is it

> The second man (the fan of Persian culture)?

The reason being that...

> Everyone enjoys an action (including baseball, which despite being a noun involves sport/action), whereas the second man is simply a fan of a given culture.

Comment: If you try to find the odd one out based directly on their hobbies, you'll always find something different. There is a much more solid fit once you got it ;)

Comment: This was my take, too. But this sadly gives no reason why they would not feel welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Granted this is a long shot, but is it:

> The woman who likes to slice things up?

Reason being:

> You say she's "another woman", which is a colloquial term for "mistress".  When she says that she likes to "slice things up", the other people could understand the "thing" to be a marriage or other relationship, and this comment could be seen as being in very poor taste.

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> The man who likes eating at evening.

Because:

> He interjects himself into a conversation with the two couples and wasn't originally a part of the conversation in the first place.

Comment: Sorry but... no.