# Wrap Your Head Around This

Tags: wordplay, story

George loves watching *Helmet Teens*. It is a show about a group of four teenagers that each have a special power when they wear a space-helmet. Each helmet has their own own unique symbol, activating its own special ability
to the person wearing it — and it only works for the teens! Their names are:

> - Ethan;
> - Walter;
> - Fred; and
> - Aris.

Unfortunately, the television was playing up; during the past week, the volume was randomly turning off and no sound would play, or the channel would randomly switch off, or the entire TV would do just that.

One day, during an episode of *Helmet Teens*, the TV screen turned black — but the sound kept playing! George was trying to figure out what episode it was, until he realised it was Episode 1.

This is what he heard:

> "Greetings, humans. I am the Helmet Space Robot, home to a world of helmets. Much as you are humans, my kind living on my home planet are Helmets. Our planet is called **Helm**, and now I need you to **help** me. Listen carefully, as I will not repeat one **word** I say:
>
> Our **world** has been destroyed by war, with the powers of the helmets battling each other. Now, I am the **last** Helmetkind alive. My home planet existed in the **past**, but not anymore!
>
> As a consequence, **for** each of you, I have the **four** main helmets with the forces that used to govern our planet, so we can be remembered. Put these on, and you shall have powers beyond human strength."

This was the Helmet Space Robot, of course. Then spoke the four teens. George was waiting to hear their voices, but then the sound cut out and the subtitles appeared on the screen.

> "Mother nature! This helmet is so down to me!" 
>  "Cool! Everything else seems like me under the bridge!" 
>  "Holy flame! I am so up myself, right now!" 
>  "Knock me off my feet! I'm walking on myself!"

Somehow, George was able to tell which teen was telling which line, and which teen was receiving which helmet. (He was just beginning to actually enjoy the show, to his surprise, when suddenly the TV blew up and he had to tell his parents to get a new one.)

**How did he do it?** 
 **What was the helmet each teenager was given?** 
 **What was each of their special abilities?** 
 
 *Bonus 50 rep bounty reward if (and only if!) you have answered the three previous questions*: 
 **What is the secret message hidden in** ***Helmet Teens***${}$**?**

---

The title seems unrelated... but it is a clue.

**Edit:** 
 Forgot to mention, this puzzle was inspired by @[Keelhaul](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43465/keelhaul)'s "[Unwelcome](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69733/whos-not-welcome-here)" puzzle. If you liked this puzzle, I suggest you check the other puzzle out if you think you haven't seen it.

Comment: How could he solve a puzzle while listening to tv? :P

Comment: As usual, @user477343 makes another spectacular puzzle :)

Comment: @KevinL thank you! But I wouldn't classify this as a riddle... though if it is considered one, I will include the `riddle` tag :D

Comment: Oops, I was so amazed that I didn't realize this wasn't a riddle :)

Comment: @KevinL **Uscfus wg am fsoz boas, pm hvs kom** :D

Comment: Oh I get it :) @user477343. Then why don't u just write that in ur profile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, the first thing I got was that

> *Helmet Teens* is an anagram for "the elements".

Further, just like the

> pairs of bolded Space Robot's words are different by only one letter, the four names are different from the names of the elements by only one letter: earth (Ethan), water (Walter), fire (Fred) and air (Aris).

If we

> replace the word "me" in what the four "teens" are saying, we get: "Mother nature! This helmet is so down to **Earth**!" [Ethan] "Cool! Everything else seems like **water** under the bridge!" [Walter] "Holy flame! I am so **fired up**, right now!" [Fred] "Knock me off my feet! I'm walking on **air**!" [Aris]

So now we know who got which helmet.

Comment: Wow. You are literally a wizard. I have to wait $12$ hours before I can upvote, as I have reached my daily voting limit. But that's not even the best part. There are two other things you will be getting, too. Since you are a puzzler, yourself, I am sure you know what they might be... However, there is only one other thing: what is the clue in the title? (It can be found in the explanation of your answer!) :D

Comment: @user477343 Thaaaaanks! :D I love puzzles like these :) I still haven't figured it out though, but I'm pretty sure it has something to do with (rot13) gubfr svefg jbeq cnvef and how they are formed.

Comment: No, not quite. Hint: (ROT13) gur "urnq" cneg ersref gb fbzrguvat boivbhf, ohg gur cuenfr "jenc lbhe urnq" vf bs pbhefr zrgncubevpny; v.r., vg vf na vqvbz... :P

Comment: I would be careful about what you say about those names, the first example does not fit the rule you came up with

Comment: @micsthepick Well actually, (ROT13) gurer ner gjb ehyrf: bar jurer lbh ercynpr n yrggre jvgu nabgure, naq bar jurer lbh gnxr njnl n yrggre :P

Comment: I now have to wait $11$ hours before I can upvote... and I haven't upvoted yet. I completely forgot to upvote this answer, and when a user upvoted this puzzle of mine about five minutes ago, I checked it out and finally remembered. Sorry about that... but that doesn't mean you don't get the tick! Congratulations!! $\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: @user477343 No problem! :D I still haven't figured out ALL of it anyway... ^^

Comment: Would that be the special abilities? I think that is pretty obvious, but I will say one other hint: (ROT13) Gur Ynfg Nveoraqre / Gur Yrtraq bs Xbeen... :D

Comment: @user477343 it does not seem to be consistent

Comment: @micsthepick Okay the answer has been ticked, this comment is way down below all the others, so I will say this without Rot13: Etha**n** $\to$ Etha**r** $\to$ **Earth**. Wa**l**ter $\to$ **Water**. Fre**d** $\to$ Fre**i** $\to$ **Fire**. Ari**s** $\to$ **Ari** $\to$ **Air**. The name Walter has the least steps, making it *flow* the quickest (like water). Now the Helmet Space Robot should provide the clues to solve this...